# Proxmox network setup - single IP multiple VMs

Tags: networking, debian, proxmox

I'm setting up my first Proxmox on a dedicated server. The bare metal provider offered me a server where I've installed Proxmox and a single IP attached to a bridged interface.

Here is the architecture I wanna build:

[image]

Some considerations:

- I wish to have the 2 physical interfaces eno1/eno2 in bounded mode for failover
- I will put a reverse NGINX proxy in front of all web based interfaces
- For each VM, I will need ssh access (port 22 local, redirected from the different ports in public (example: 141.aaa.bbb.23:221 goes to s1 port 22, 141.aaa.bbb.23:222 goes to s2 port 22, e so forth). The same for Zabbix acces (141.aaa.bbb.23:10051 goes to zabbix 10051 port).

Here is my server initial configuration:

[image]

I have some doubts about how to build the desired configuration:

a) I've created a bridge as follow for internal VMs to link the VMs, but how can I tell that bridge to go out to vmbr0 for the public internet?
[image]

b) How to bound the two interfaces together. I simply cannot create the bound between eno1 and eno2, as eno1 is attached to my public interface and if I remove that public ip I will loose access to my server.

c) How to accomplish what I need in the given architecture?

Answer (score 0):

A and C.

Your current setup is a bridged network, VMs attached to vmbr0 belong to the same network (or broadcast domain). In such a configuration, DHCP should be offered by your provider and not by the host.

The desired state is a NATted network, where VMs cannot directly send Ethernet frames to the external network and their private IP is replaced by the host IP for outgoing packets (masquerading).

You should not assign 141.aaa.bbb.23 to vmbr0 or vmbr1 devices. You can keep 141.aaa.bbb.23 assigned to the bond device, and have only vmbr0 (creating vmbr1 is not necessary).

The routing through the bond will be automatically handled by the host routing table.

See here:

- https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking
- https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#_choosing_a_network_configuration
- https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#_masquerading_nat_with_tt_span_class_monospaced_iptables_span_tt
- https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#_linux_bond

B.

> I simply cannot create the bound between eno1 and eno2, as eno1 is attached to my public interface and if I remove that public ip I will loose access to my server.

You may need an out of band management (like KVM over IP) to apply the initial configuration if it involves loss of Internet access.

Answer (score 0):

> I simply cannot create the bound between eno1 and eno2, as eno1 is attached to my public interface and if I remove that public ip I will loose access to my server.

Welcome to the jungle.

Given the constraints, without remote console access and in the absence of willing collusion by the hosting provider, you have no choice. Either you change one of these factors or....

What you could do is create a new config file (Proxmox uses /etc/network/interfaces) say /etc/network/proposed, backup your working config as, say, /etc/network/working then create cron jobs to deploy each of these and apply changes. Set the cron job for "proposed" to run at, say 3pm, and "working" at 4pm.

The bonded config would look something like...

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

iface eno2 inet manual

iface bond0 inet manual
      bond-slaves eno1 eno2
      bond-miimon 100
      bond-mode balance-rr
      
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 141.aaa.bbb.23/24
        gateway 1141.aaa.bbb.1
        bridge-ports bond0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '141.aaa.bbb.23/24' -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '141.aaa.bbb.23/24' -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE

iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 192.168.0.1/24
```

> example: 141.aaa.bbb.23:221 goes to s1 port 22, 141.aaa.bbb.23:222 goes to s2 port 22

?

Just use your Proxmox host as a jump box....

```
ssh -J 141.aaa.bbb.23 192.168.0.102
```

(you can pre-configure this in ~/.ssh/ssh_config)